# jQuery getJSON url

Tags: php, javascript, json, twitter

I am setting up a twitter feed into my site and have it working perfectly when you access it with a root page ie www.domain.com/index.php

However when you have a url that is www.domain.com/category/page it doesn't not work, however if you use www.domain.com/index.php?cat=category&page=page it works fine.

So in the javascript I have the following

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery.getJSON('cache/twitter-json.txt', function(data){
    jQuery.each(data, function(index, item){
    jQuery('#tweet').append('code for displaying tweet');
});
});
```

So I have tried to change the url in the getJSON function to the full path www.domain.com/cache/twitter-json.txt but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
jQuery.getJSON('/cache/twitter-json.txt', function(data){
```

Relative URLs are interpreted relative to the directory of the page containing the reference. So when you make the above call from `www.domain.com/category/page`, it tries to go to `www.domain.com/category/cache/twitter-json.txt`.

If you want to use the full URL, you need to put `//` before the hostname, e.g.

```
jQuery.getJSON('//www.domain.com/cache/twitter-json.txt', function(data){
```

Otherwise, it thinks `www.domain.com/` is just another level of directory.

Comment: Thanks Barmar that make sense but unfortunately thats not fixed it, it has also stop working in the domain.com/index.php

Comment: Maybe there's a rewrite rule that's messing with it? Otherwise, it should work like this.

Comment: The only rewrite rules i have are RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&game=$2 [L]

Comment: Can you check your access log to see what URL it's trying to access for twitter-json.txt, and compare that with where the file really is?

Comment: Nothing in there that is telling what is causing the issue, the file paths look right

Comment: Does it say that the request is successful? Do you see any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Thanks Barmar, got it working, forgot about the javascript console, had a couple of errors which I have now fixed.

Answer (score 2):

change

```
jQuery.getJSON('cache/twitter-json.txt', function(data){
```

to

```
jQuery.getJSON('/cache/twitter-json.txt', function(data){
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it helps to set the base in your html

```
<base href="http://myserver/dir1/">
```