# Acess local file JSON subfolder using getJSON ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, getjson

I'm stuck on a simple problem of request from local file using JSON. Here's the code:

```
     $.getJSON("/assets/data/dados.json")
        .done(function(dados){
            console.log(dados);
        })
        .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error){
            console.error(jqxhr);
            console.error(textStatus);
            console.error(error);
        });
```

And here's the `dados.json` file:

```
[
{
    "nome": "Alabama",
    "abreviacao": "AL"
},
{
    "nome": "Alaska",
    "abreviacao": "AK"
}
]
```

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/16844246/3214471

Comment: No, you can't access the file system. And this is a good thing for whose who like security.

Comment: Thank you all!
@AswinRamesh: This is not helped my problem, i checked and my syntax is correct. But i glad that you helped!

Comment: @Hitmands: With pure javascript it seems to work, but why with ajax it won't seems to work?